# Record audio with mp4 format in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to record audio in html in mp4 format. I have already found audio recording in wav format using [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs). Is there any way to record audio in mp4 format?